# Not work TransitionPresets. react-navigation version 6

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I recently upgraded from v4 to v6.
As a result, TransitionPresets seems to have stopped working.

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={Home}
  options={{ ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS }}
/>
```

I don't think there is any wrong way to use it.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transitionpresets

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

#### Edit 2021-11-17

I'm sorry.
I guess I did not understand the difference between native stack and stack.
I used the normal stack and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In navigation v6

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    animation: 'fade_from_bottom',
  }}>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

animation options should be :

```
StackAnimationTypes = 'default' | 'fade' | 'fade_from_bottom' | 'flip' | 'none' | 'simple_push' | 'slide_from_bottom' | 'slide_from_right' | 'slide_from_left'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, when switching versions and editing a way of writing Stack I noticed that they redirected to different libs.

Change from:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

For:

```
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets, } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

And also edited when creating the Stack of:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
```

For:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add TransitionPresets in screenOptions props in Stack.Navigator. Just put same as follows.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="screenName" component={screenComponent} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```